# ESTA / Visa Waiver Program - volunteering

Tags: usa, esta

I am a german student, graduating this spring. I did an exchange year in 11th grade in Tennessee, USA. Since I´m still in touch with my friends and host family, I got a chance to volunteer in the local hospital. In the ESTA program condition it says, I can ´attend a short-term training´. So my question is, is my volunteer work, where don't get paid in any source, considered as a short-term training? 
I appreciate every help I can get.

Aaron